# Does OpenMP support async operations?

Tags: c, async-await, promise, openmp, future

I have been using Javascript for a while and I like its async operations, using either callbacks or promises and futures. Now I need to use OpenMP and failed to find any support for these features.

Are callbacks and/or futures supported by OpenMP?

Comment: On which platform, in what language are you going to use OpenMP?

Comment: @Bergi I am using default language C on Linux platform.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can do a lot with threads and tasks.

Comment: @derek, if you're looking to do event-based programming with C on Linux then you might want to consider using a library such as [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html). OpenMP's model is based around splitting large quantities of CPU-intensive work between available cores (ie "number crunching"), it doesn't fit the description of what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are callbacks and/or futures supported by OpenMP?

Simple answer: No.

OpenMP is designed for parallelism (i.e. using multiple hardware threads to compute the answer to a single problem simultaneously), not concurrency (i.e. providing rapid interaction with the outside world by expressing computation as callbacks to be triggered on events).

These are different styles and application areas. Consider that using concurrency simplifies your code and is useful even on single-threaded hardware, whereas parallelism is pointless there, since its objective is to use all the available CPUs.

OpenMP is probably the wrong tool to be using to handle concurrent programming, since it wasn't designed for that task.